# Highcharts Broken Line / Line Segment

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to have multiple line segments treated as 1 line? IE: I hover over one, both get highlighted, and toggling the visibility in the legend will hide both segments.

http://jsfiddle.net/rayholland/HSvBj/2/

```
series: [
    {
        type: 'line',
        data: [{x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:1}],
        events: {
            legendItemClick: function(event) {
                this.visible? 
                    this.chart.get('group1').hide():
                    this.chart.get('group1').show();
            }
        }
    },{
        type: 'line',
        data: [{x:3,y:1},{x:4,y:0}],
        showInLegend: false,
        id: 'group1'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think if I treat it as 1 line but then have a null value in the middle as a separator it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/rayholland/HSvBj/4/

```
data: [{x:0,y:0},{x:1,y:1},{x:null,y:null},{x:3,y:1},{x:4,y:0}]
```

Comment: I don't think this is an expectable answer as this data series will result in Highcharts Error #15: http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15, check out the browser inspection at the above jsfiddle.